# What is the history of the use of the term "scalene triangle"?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, education, triangles

A "scalene triangle" is a triangle with three unequal sides. As far as I can tell, this term is not in much use in serious mathematics — in fact, before I became a high school math teacher, I'd forgotten the term existed. However, it is almost universally stressed as an important class of triangles in high school geometry courses in the United States.

I have two questions:

**Q1**: Who developed/popularized the use of the term scalene to refer to triangles of this type? Why, even, is this term useful? Unlike "isosceles" or "equilateral," being "scalene" is not really a special property of a triangle, but rather seems to be the default condition of an arbitrary triangle.

**Q2**: How was this term enshrined in American geometry education? Is there any justification for its prominence in the standard curriculum?

Comment: Your Q2 might also be of interest at [matheducators.SE].

Answer (score 4):

[Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics](http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html) traces "scalene" (in English) back to 1570.  But I expect Euclid used  σκαληνός.

Comment: Terrific resource, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Robert Israel is correct:  Euclid introduces "equilateral", "isosceles" and "scalene" (spelled $\sigma \kappa \alpha \lambda \eta \nu \acute{\omicron} \nu$) in Definition 20 of Book I of the Elements.

Source:  Richard Fitzpatrick's edition of the *Elements*, available at [www.aproged.pt/biblioteca/elementseuclid.pdf](http://www.aproged.pt/biblioteca/elementseuclid.pdf).